# Building an Executable that Can't be Ran

Tags: gcc, makefile, exe

I am getting `vk: command not found` when running `vk`, and getting `bash: ./vk: No such file or directory` when executing `./vk`.

I did some research and the cause is usually that it isa 32bit exe on a 64bit machine

make builds the output to `vk/_target`. I `cd` to _target

When I run `file vk` I get this back.

> vk: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld6, not stripped

I have tried executing `chmod +x vk` and `chmod u+x vk`. I have tried every combination of typing `./vk` and `vk` with `chmod`. I'm at a loss here. I have passed `-m64` as an option to `gcc`, but that seems to be the default.

Here is my makefile

```
CFLAGS = -m64 -Wall -O3
CC = gcc
LINKER = ld -lc --entry main
DUMP = objdump
COPY = objcopy
TARGET_DIR = _target

SRCS := $(shell find ./ -name \*.c)
VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(SRCS)))
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(TARGET_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))

$(TARGET_DIR)/vk : $(OBJS)
    $(LINKER) $^ -o $@
    $(DUMP) -D $@ > $(@:=.list)

$(TARGET_DIR)/%.o : %.c folders
    @echo "compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "assembly dump $@"
    $(DUMP) -D $@ > $@.list

.PHONY: folders

folders:
    mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET_DIR)
```

Comment: Please give *exact steps* required to reproduce the behavior you describe.  The combination of symptoms presented do not seem to all be consistent with each other.  In particular, the `bash` error message is not consistent with the output from `file` unless there are some other steps between, such as changing the working directory.

Comment: @JohnBollinger updated.

Comment: Can you share output from `cd _target ; ls -l ./vk ; file ./vk ; ./vk` ? Also consider sharing the output of 'make', (compacting the compile steps, if too many files)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you disassemble the binary after linking and compiling. Must take lot of space/time.

Comment: By "exact steps", I mean a complete sequence of the commands you execute, starting with the `make` command and including each command whose output you've reported and every command between.  Effectively, a script.  As it stands, the question remains unclear about the order in which you execute commands, and in particular, about where the `cd` command appears in the sequence.

Comment: Quite common case is when the binary requests an interpreter (dynamic loader) that is not available on the machine. You can try to run `readelf -l vk` and search for `Requesting program interpreter` - check whether the interpreter requested is present, also compare with some regular system binary, i.e. `readelf -l /bin/ls`.